# ClientLogin from Google API doesn't works with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, picasa

I'm trying to login to a Google Account for request Picassa Web photos with AJAX. That's the code:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://www.google.com/accounts/Login",true);
xmlhttp.send("accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=...&Passwd=...&service=lh2&source=prova");
document.getElementById('prova').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

With this firebug shows a 200 OK status in the Net tab but an unexplained error in the Console. Of course nothing appears in the div called "prova" since answer is empty.

I also try to add this header:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

But then firebug shows a 400 Bad Request in the Net tab. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Solved! Firefox and new browsers don't let make AJAX call to third-party applications for security reasons. All is explained here:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/11/09/fixing-ajax-xmlhttprequest-considered-harmful.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Firefox and new browsers don't let make AJAX call to third-party applications for security reasons. All is explained here: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/11/09/fixing-ajax-xmlhttprequest-considered-harmful.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view the ajax reponse in firebug and see what is gtting posted back to you - you can get a 200 error but still get an error in the post back. Don't you need to do something with an AuthToken too?

Comment: The response is empty :( I want the AuthToken to get photos from a picassaweb account, but I would simplify the problem. In fact, at the beginning I was using Prototype but I decide to do it without frameworks with the aim of understand the problem.

Comment: just googled a bit - does the picasa api actually support javascript? I've only every used curl to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure if we got the authToken or not...

Here's how I've been making xDomain Posts:

It requires having a little library (tiny) called [flyJSONP](http://alotaiba.github.com/FlyJSONP/), which uses YQL (Yahoo! Query Language) as a JSONP hack.  Works great, but **cannot post/get headers**.  After, I send data to php which then makes a cross-domain post with necessary header.

FlyJSONP also works with get... FlyJSONP.get({...

```
    FlyJSONP.post({
        url: "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin",
        parameters: {
            name: "value"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("the response is: " + data);
        },
        error: function(errorMsg) {
            console.log(errorMsg);
        },
        complete: function(data){
            console.log("...completed post!");
        }
    });
```